# Sort arrays into groups, add remainders ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array of 13 players

```
players = ['andre','ben','cameron','deshawn','emmanuel','freddy','gabriel','henry','ian','jadeveon','kentavious','lance','malik']
```

I want a method which sorts the players into teams of 4 using code similar to this:

```
def teams(array)
  groups = [] 
  array.shuffle.each_slice(4) { |group| groups << group } 
  groups
end
```

Given an array of players whose length is indivisible by 4, how do I add the remainders to the existing groups?  For example, if I have an array of 13 players, How do I output 2 teams of 4 and one team of 5?  Etc for an array of 22...

Expected output

```
[['freddy','malik','cameron','deshawn','jadeveon'],['lance','kentavious','gabriel','ian'],['emmanuel','henry','ben','andre']]
```

Comment: I didn't get the logic of expected output.. It is misleading for me..

Comment: Do you want `N%4` groups to have one extra player?

Comment: why the size is 5,4,4 ?

Comment: @AShelly If you do that, it not matched the output.. logic sucks.. :-)

Comment: Just want to have groups of 4 with extra players added to those groups as needed

Comment: based on what, I should decide when team size will be 4 or 5 ?

Comment: Based on whether or not the total number of players is divisible by 4, default is teams of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I wish to thank @AShelly for catching a flaw in my original solution, noting that my code produced incorrect results when their were 11 players.  As it turns out, it was producing erroneous answers for all the examples I gave, but, evidently, no one noticed.  Where below I have `each_slice(players.size/4)`, I formerly had `each_slice(4)`.  I believe the code is now OK.

**Code**

```
def deal_players(players)
  shuffled = players.shuffle
  shuffled.shift(4*(players.size/4)).each_slice(players.size/4).map { |g|
    shuffled.any? ? g + [shuffled.shift] : g }
end
```

**Examples**

```
players = ['andre','ben','cameron','deshawn','emmanuel','freddy',
           'gabriel','henry','ian','jadeveon','kentavious']

deal_players(players)
  #=> [["emmanuel", "jadeveon"  , "gabriel"],
  #    ["cameron" , "henry"     , "ben"    ],
  #    ["freddy"  , "kentavious", "ian"    ],
  #    ["deshawn" , "andre"                ]]

players = ['andre','ben','cameron','deshawn','emmanuel','freddy','gabriel',
           'henry','ian','jadeveon','kentavious','lance','malik','betty']

deal_players(players)
   #=> [["betty"   , "ian"   , "henry"  , "kentavious"],
   #    ["ben"     , "freddy", "deshawn", "malik"     ],
   #    ["emmanuel", "lance" , "cameron"              ],
   #    ["gabriel" , "andre" , "jadeveon"             ]]
```

**Explanation**

```
players = ['andre','ben','cameron','deshawn','emmanuel','freddy','gabriel',
           'henry','ian','jadeveon','kentavious','lance','malik']

shuffled = players.shuffle
  #=> ["ben", "henry", "lance", "emmanuel", "malik", "cameron", "freddy",
  #    "deshawn", "andre", "jadeveon", "kentavious", "gabriel", "ian"]

a = shuffled.shift(4*(players.size/4))
  #=> ["ben", "henry", "lance", "emmanuel", "malik", "cameron", "freddy",
  #   "deshawn", "andre", "jadeveon", "kentavious", "gabriel"]

shuffled #=> ["ian"]

b = a.each_slice(players.size/4)
  #=>#<Enumerator:["ben","henry","lance","emmanuel","malik","cameron","freddy",
  #    "deshawn","andre","jadeveon","kentavious","gabriel"]:each_slice(3)>
```

To view contents of enumerator:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [["ben"     , "henry"     , "lance"  ],
  #    ["emmanuel", "malik"     , "cameron"],
  #    ["freddy"  , "deshawn"   , "andre"  ],
  #    ["jadeveon", "kentavious", "gabriel"]]

b.map { |g| shuffled.any? ? g + [shuffled.shift] : g }
  #=> [["ben"     , "henry"     , "lance", "ian"],
  #    ["emmanuel", "malik"     , "cameron"     ],
  #    ["freddy"  , "deshawn"   , "andre"       ],
  #    ["jadeveon", "kentavious", "gabriel"     ]]
```

This last step merely adds one of the remaining players (between 0 and 3) in `shuffled` to each of the array elements of `b` until there are no more to be added.  Here, `shuffled` contains only "ian", so "ian" is added to the first group.

Comment: This leaves out one player for a group of 11.

Comment: @AShelly, thanks for the catch.  As it turns out, the problem was not just with 11 players (see edit).

Answer (score 3):

```
groups = array.shuffle.each_slice(4).to_a
spares = groups.pop if groups[-1].size != 4
spares.each_with_index{|p,i| groups[i]<<p}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work for all numbers, because the problem is not well defined. What would you do if there were 11 players?  This  solution turns `[4],[4],[3]` into  `[5]+[5]+NoMethodError`.  This is probably not ideal. Is the expected distribution of 11 `[6],[5]` , `[5],[5],[1]`, `[4],[4],[3]` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

not the most concise solution, but this should work:

```
 if team.length%num == 0
    teams = team.each_slice(num).to_a
  else
    total = (team.length).divmod(num)       //returns array[0]=quotent, array[1]=remainder
    extra_players= team.shift(total[1]) 
    final_teams = team.each_slice(total[0]).to_a
    remainder_players.each do |x| 
      final_teams.sample.push(x)                 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game on this one, but I'm doing nearly the exact same thing. (with an additional twist).
Sort a group of unknkown size (I had defined as > 11, but it works with smaller numbers too) into teams of not more than 5.  (> 11 it's teams of 5 or 4).
I grabbed a deck of cards, cut random number from the deck.
Counted the size of the cut,  and divided by 5 and rounded up to nearest integer.
In the example above,  11 / 5 = 2.2, rounded up to 3 to determine number of teams.
Now just deal the cards into 3 piles, and you end up with piles (teams) of 4, 4 & 3.
Again, with numbers greater than 11, they will all be teams of 5 or 4.

- my twist is I need each hand/pile/team to to be balanced based on the total value of each hand. I'll post that as a new question.